# Using Monitor for Thread Synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to get started with multithreading in C#. I am trying to write a program with two threads - given a number n, one thread would print all even numbers upto n and the other thread would print all the odd numbers. I am trying to have both these threads synchronize using Monitor so that they print the numbers in sequence.

Following is what I have come up with so far, which running into deadlock. How do I correct this? Also, please help me understand what is the significance of the object sent to Pulse and Wait? I couldnt understand from the documentation.

```
    class NumPrint
{
    public Thread other{get; set;}

    int first, max;

    public NumPrint(int first, int max, bool thisFlag) 
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.max = max;            
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = first; i <= max; i+=2)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                lock (this)
                {
                    Monitor.Pulse(this);
                }
                lock (other)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(other);
                }
        }
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NumPrint odd = new NumPrint(1, 10,false);
        NumPrint even = new NumPrint(2, 10, true);


        Thread oddThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(odd.DoWork));
        Thread evenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(even.DoWork));

        odd.other = evenThread;
        even.other = oddThread;

        oddThread.Start();
        evenThread.Start();

        oddThread.Join();
        evenThread.Join();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing the wrong argument to Monitor.Pulse(), pulsing the lock you already own has no effect.  You possibly meant to pass *other* to release another thread that's blocked inside the other lock.  Not that this will work either, Pulse() only releases a waiting thread and you cannot be sure that another thread has entered the lock.  The real solution is to simply use *one* thread and have it call odd(), then even().  Always the right order that way and a *lot* less overhead and no loss of throughput.

Comment: @HansPassant - your statement regarding Monitor.Pulse() having no effect when you already own the lock is incorrect, indeed you can *only* call Pulse on an object for which you currently hold the lock: (Per the remarks of: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx - "Only the current owner of the lock can signal a waiting object using Pulse").

Answer (score 0):

As others have already outlined here only current owner of the lock can signal using pulse.

I would highly recommend tutorial by Joe Albahari.

http://www.albahari.com/threading/